# How to find the marginal densities of the given functions

Tags: probability, distributions, covariance

The fraction $X$ of male runners and the fraction $Y$ of female runners who compete
in marathon races are described by the joint density function$$f(x,y) =  \begin{cases} 8xy &  0 \le x \le y \le1 \\ 0 & \mbox{elsewhere,} \end{cases}$$

Find the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ .

I know the formula as $σ_{xy}=E(XY ) − μ_Xμ_Y $

And the given solution is as follows

We first compute the marginal density functions. They are

$$g(x) =  \begin{cases} 4x^3 &  0 \le x \le1 \\ 0 & \mbox{elsewhere.} \end{cases}$$

and $$h(y) =  \begin{cases} 4y(1 − y^2) &  0 \le y \le1 \\ 0 & \mbox{elsewhere.} \end{cases}$$

**My Question:**

How did they get $g(x)$ and $h(y)$?

Did they use $\int_0^1 f(x,y)$ dy and $\int_0^1f(x,y)dx$?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and expand on the difficulties you have with notions like marginal densities and covariance of continuous variables. In particular explain why you did not try to compute $\int_0^1 f(x,y)\text{d}x = h(y)$

Comment: See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/365913/6633) for some details about the marginal density can be derived from the joint density.

Answer (score 1):

Since your joint is non-zero when $x\leq y$, $h(y)=\int_0^{y}{f(x,y)dx}$. And, it appears that your $h(y)$ is not true, PDF of Y should be $f_Y(y)=g(y)$. Or the initial condition should be $y\leq x$. Anyway, after finding marginals, you calculate the means. And for $E[XY]$, you'll just perform a joint integration by *respecting* the limits.