# what is the conditional density of $X$ given $Y$?

Tags: random-variable, joint-distribution

If the joint p.d.f of a two-dimensional random variable $(X,Y)$ is given by:

$f(x,y) = \  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      2 &s.t.~ 0<x<1;~0 <y<x \\
      0 &x <0~;~x>1 \\
\end{array} 
\right. $

Then, what is the conditional density of $X$ given $Y$?

**Attempt**: $f_{X|Y}(x|y)= \dfrac{P_{XY}(x,y)}{P_Y(y)}$

As per given condition : $\int^0_1 (\int_0^xP_{XY}(x,y)~dy) dx=2$

How does one calculate $P_{XY}(x,y)$ from here.

Also, I have trouble visualizing a way to find out $P_Y(y) = \int_0^\infty P_{XY}(x,y)~ dx$

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Duplicate of [How to find density function from this joint probability density function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365715/how-to-find-density-function-from-this-joint-probability-density-function) with the minor difference that the support here is $0 < y < x < 1$ whereas in the cited question, the support is $0 < x < y < 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f_Y(y)=\int_y^1 f(x,y)dx=2\int_y^1 dx=2(1-y), 0<y<1$
$f_{X|Y}(x|y)= \dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}=\dfrac{2}{2(1-y)}=\dfrac{1}{1-y}, 0<y<1$

Comment: No, this is wrong, The conditional pdf $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)$ is a function of $x$, not of $y$ ($y$ is just a parameter in the formulas that you might come up with).